# Output specific Text on field change

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

i have got a small problem.

I have an extension with a date field.

There is a list with events for a full year and I want to group them by month.

To do that I want to output a headline which contains the Month and on each change of a month in a date field a new headline should be printed.

How can I manage that?

Is there an easy way?

The Actual Code looks like this:

```
<f:link.action action="show" arguments="{operation:operation}" pageUid="{settings.operationSinglePid}">
<table>
<tr>
<td width="70px">[{operation.number}]</td>
<td width="170px"> <f:if condition="{operation.begin}">
                                {operation.begin -> f:format.date(format:'d.m.Y, H:i \U\h\r')}
                        </f:if></td>
<td width="260px">Stichwort:


<f:for each="{operation.type}" as="stichwort">
{stichwort.title}
</f:for>





</td>
<td width="300px"> <f:if condition="{operation.location}">
                        <span>{operation.location}</span>
                </f:if>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</f:link.action>
```

Regards and thank you

Sascha Urbansky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view helper like [`vhs:variable.set`](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Variable/SetViewHelper.html), set the month before the loop and compare this variable in every loop iteration with the current one. If it changes, change the variable again.
Or use the [groupedFor](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/GroupedForViewHelper.html) view helper if your data structures fits.

Comment: Hi. Thats it. Thanks a lot. Do you know any good how tos or tutorials on how to get started with fluid, extbase and extension programming??